# I plan to buy any FPGA boards, any idea for a good sources of information? and what coin is profitable?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-hardware, fpga

Do you guys know any good source for newbie FPGA miners?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://fpga.guide/en/ is a good place for beginners who want to learn about fpga mining. they also have a [calculator page](https://fpga.guide/en/mining-profit-calculator/) so you can find out which coin is the most profitable

Comment: emmm, interesting, thank youuu,
have you mine with FPGA already?

Comment: Yes, I've been mining with FPGAs for over a year. If you want to start out, I suggest you start with an F1 Mini or something